# Azure Search contain

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Im using azure search on my project,
This is information in the search field:

```
Document:{
field_name1: "this is the first value, new value",
field_name2: "My Name"
}
```

Now, I put the search term "new value" in field_name1 on search method:

```
"(field_name1:/.*new value.*/)"
```

But nothing to return.

So anyone could help me?

Comment: The issue you are facing could be because of a variety of reasons - is the field that you search on marked as searchable? Do you have any custom analyzers, which may interfere with the default indexing mechanism? Are you modifying the minimumCoverage parameter at all? To help getting a correct answer for your question, could you please add more details to your question? Such as the index definition details and answers to some of my questions?

FYI, you can read more about searching documents here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents

Answer (score -1):

Your code looks fine and it should work. Make Sure
your Search Parameter should have SearchMode.Any and QueryType.Full as mentioned below.

```
SearchParameters()
{
     SearchMode = SearchMode.Any,
     QueryType = QueryType.Full
};
```